# Function to retrieve the product version during install

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wix, windows-installer, version

I want to retrieve the product version during the install time of a .msi in the source file of the .dll which is linked with the .msi. Is there a way to do this with C++/Visual C++.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit difficult , what i understand is you want to do some validation , have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31021/Getting-version-from-MSI-without-installing-it

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have had a look at the WIX-HowTo first, they extract the dll-version for error-generation ("your... dll is outdated...")

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm